# What does this error mean - "No matching CIPHER found"?

Tags: perl, unix, ssh

Although I'm OK in PERL, this below error is new for me and I'm not exactly aware of why it is occurring.
Can some one let me understand why this error occurs and how to fix this?
Is this similar to like some Module is missing?

```
No matching cipher found: client 3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,arcfour server aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/SSH/Perl/SSH2.pm line 92
```

Comment: Under what circumstances is the error happening?

Comment: does this happen when you try to connect to the host?

Comment: It probably means that the encryption method used is not supported on the target machine.

Comment: she needs to configure her config file or try connecting using Net::OpenSSH instead of Net::SSH::Perl

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson  This happens when I'm trying to connect to client SFTP server. And one big doubt in my mind is I could see that I can able to connect to this SFTP server and can transfer files as well, But how come it works when it is throwing an error? Is it just a warning? It wont have any effect on the process?

Comment: @RachelGallen - Yes Gallen as I mentioned in my above comment, I'm trying to connect to SFTP server.

Comment: @Amareesh then read my other comment and read this http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1389656

Comment: @RachelGallen - Thanks but one more thing I need to confirm is that my script is running in UNIX environment and I'm not using NET::SSH::PERL module. I'm using Net::SFTP module to connect to SFTP server.

Comment: NET::SSH supports bith unix and SFTP http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20141/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%Net.SSH.SFTP

Comment: @RachelGallen - Thanks for the information!!
Now I'm facing new problem, even I couldn't connect to the SFTP server using Net::SFTP. Below is the error which I'm receiving now.
It used to work previously but now it is throwing an error.

Can't locate object method "_session_channel" via package "Net::SSH::Perl::SSH1"
 at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/SFTP.pm line 78.

Comment: @Amareesh my suggestion was that u use Net::OpenSSH did you not try that?  http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-OpenSSH-0.62/lib/Net/OpenSSH.pm

Comment: @RachelGallen - This particular module Net::OpenSSH  was not installed in the server. If that is the case then I need to raise a request to my Admin team to install this module, which will take some more time. Is there any other way or why Net::SFTP is not working?

Comment: @Amareesh your error is a widely reported error when using that SSH Perl. OPenSSH is much more well supported. i would advise installing. if you can find an answer on google you'd be lucky

Comment: @Amareesh, in order to use Net::OpenSSH/Net::SFTP::Foreign, you don't need to install then on the server, just on the client!

Comment: @salva - Which module I have to mention in my script inorder to use Net::OpenSSH? I'm not aware of the thing which you have mentioned. Is that means these modules should be already be installed on client server inorder to use them on our side?

Comment: @Amareesh: you need to install also Net::SFTP::Foreign on the client machine if you want to use sftp with Net::OpenSSH

Answer (score 8):

It means exactly what it says:

> `No matching cipher found:`

The SSH server you're connecting to cannot or will not support any of the ciphers that your SSH client knows.

> `client 3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,arcfour`

Your client could use [3DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) or [Blowfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_(cipher)) in CBC [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation), or the [RC4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4) stream cipher.  All of these are fairly old ciphers, although they're still considered secure if used correctly.

> `server aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc`

The server will only use [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) (with any of the three standard key sizes) in CTR or CBC modes.  Since your client can't or won't use AES, the server and the client have no ciphers in common.  Basically, they don't speak any common language, and so cannot communicate properly.

> `at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/SSH/Perl/SSH2.pm line 92`

Based on this part of the error message, it seems that you're using the [Net::SSH::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-SSH-Perl/) module.
Alas, according to the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::SSH::Perl#BASIC_USAGE), Net::SSH::Perl just plain doesn't support AES, so you're not going to be able to use it to talk to this server (unless AES support is added in some later version, of course).  Sorry.

In the comments, you say that you're actually using [Net::SFTP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::SFTP), which is then using Net::SSH::Perl internally.  If so, you might want to consider switching to either [Net::SFTP::Foreign](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::SFTP::Foreign) (which has a [compatibility wrapper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::SFTP::Foreign::Compat) for Net::SFTP) or [Net::SSH2::SFTP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::SSH2::SFTP).  The downside (if you consider it such) is that neither of these is a pure-Perl module: Net::SFTP::Foreign requires an external `ssh` command to be installed, while Net::SSH2::SFTP needs the external libssh2 library.

Comment: *"The SSH server you're connecting to cannot or will not support any of the ciphers that your SSH client knows"* There is more to the key exchange than agreeing on a cipher. *"This error comes from the `Net::SSH::Perl::SSH2` module"*. No it doesn't, except indirectly -- you may as well say that the error comes from the OP's prgram. It is the key exchange module `Net::SSH::Perl::Kex` that generates this message.

Comment: @Borodin: The error message specifically says "No matching cipher found". There certainly is more to SSH connection setup than agreeing on a cipher, but that's what the error is about. As for the source of the message, technically, you're right, but it doesn't really make much difference. What matters is that it's coming from within the Net::SSH::Perl distribution, which, in particular, tells us that the OP is using that module, rather than one of the various other Perl SSH client implementations out there.

Comment: I mostly agree, but that isn't what you said in your answer which is misleading. If ***it doesn't make much difference*** then why did you ascribe it to the wrong module at all?

Comment: @Borodin: Because I didn't bother to read the source code, and thus didn't realize that it was produced by a (poorly used) `croak` instead of a plain old `die`. Anyway, I already edited my answer to mention the actual source of the message, and even credited you for the correction.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how in Perl the configuration is done, but there is a simple fix if you use the Linux native ssh. Here is the solution:

Linux ssh client can be configured to use one of the allowed ciphers on the server. One way to do it is to modify ~/.ssh/config with this:

```
Host gitlab.com
     Ciphers aes256-ctc
```

I am sure there is similar configuration in the Perl module usage.

Answer (score 1):

This is a message from the [`Net::SSH::Perl::Kex`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Perl::Kex) module. It is generated when the `choose_ciph` method of a `Net::SSH::Perl::Kex` object is called. Essentially the client/server dialogue that establishes the parameters of the communication has found no solution that is acceptable to both parties

If you show your code and can give details of the server system then we can help further